# save a modal message in database issue

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

My main idea is to show data from database and beside each row, there is an accept and reject button .onClick, the value of the button gets passed to controller and saved to database.so far so good, the issue is when I tried to add a popup modal that has input text to add a note . it should appear only when I click the reject button only. I opened the developer tools and found it passes the double of the whole number of the data rows and i don't know how to pass the id of the row I'm in, the value of the rejected button and finally the message that is going to be written to the controller. I tried to pass the modal in the reject button method in the controller but it passes as null. what am I doing wrong? is my script part is organized or even accurate after I added the ajax or not?
I appreciate any help.
my view:

```
@model AllmyTries.Models.fulfillmentVM


<!-- page content -->


                                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Add_Fulfillment_Reject", "Feedback", FormMethod.Post))
                                    {
                                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                                        <td>
                                            <button id="btnReject" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" name="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" type="submit" onclick="reject(0)" value="0">Reject</button>
                                            @Html.Hidden("Request_ID", Model._Requests[i].Request_ID)
                                            @Html.Hidden("Status", Model._Requests[i].Status, new { id = "myEdit", value = "" })
                                        </td>

                                        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                                <div class="modal-content">
                                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
                                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                        </button>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                                        <form id="myform">

                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </form>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                        <input type="reset" value="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="finalSave" />

                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    }


<!-- /page content -->


@section Scripts {
    <script>

        $('[name = "button"]').click(function () {
            $('[name = "Status"]').val($('[name = "button"]').val());

        })

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#finalSave').click(function () {
                var dataform = $('#myform').serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/Feedback/Add_Fulfillment_Reject',
                    data: dataform,
                    success: function () {
                        $('#exampleModal').modal('hide');
                    }

                })

            })
        })

    </script>
}
```

the controller:

```
        #region fulfillment
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Add_Fulfillment_Accept(int Request_ID, int? Status)
        {
            var user = db.TBL_Request.Find(Request_ID);

            user.Inserted_by = Status ?? 0;

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
//this is the one with the issue 
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Add_Fulfillment_Reject(fulfillmentVM vM)
        {
            //save the status
            //save the note


            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        #endregion


    }
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and eliminate the unnecessary code?  We only need to see the code that's relevant to your question.

Comment: @devlincarnate I edit it and placed the reject button code in the view

Comment: Your `onClick` event calls a method called `reject(0)` - there isn't a method called `reject` and it's also a submit button (you're inside a form)... You also have another submit button down below, which will execute the backend code based on your Form definition, but you also have an AJAX method down below to execute it based on the name... Why?

Comment: @ragerory the `onClick` was one of my tries and is useless, I removed it . the ajax is for taking the text that will be written inside the modal to the controller or how else I'm going to pass it?.the button in the modal submit, my idea is for passing the data to the controller.do you suggest I edit the button or the ajax ?? or what should I do?

Comment: @ragerory, when I removed the `type="submit " ` from the button of the reject and placed it with `type=" button" ` .i, ran the application and onClick, it shows the popup and takes the text but when I click submit it closes and doesn't go to the controller.

Comment: When you put a submit button inside a `using(BeginForm...)` statement, it executes the action of the controller you supply there and passes the `ViewModel` in the current context to the signature. Why is your modal HTML inside the `BeginForm`? It shouldn't be.

Comment: Is the issue that the modal doesn't correctly display? Or is the issue with the submission of the form?

Comment: @NathanMiller the submission of the form. it's passed as null to the reject method in the controller. I know the error is between the ajax and the buttons but I can't figure which one exactly and what to correct?

Comment: @ragerory okay, I placed it outside the form but it does the same issue .takes the text and closes .i put a breakpoint in the reject method , it should go there when I click the modal button.

Comment: @ragerory I ran the application again after I removed the modal with its submit button outside the form. the model passed to the controller as null. I thought putting the modal inside the form will pass all its values when I click submit that's why i placed it first inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Javascript submits only the textarea that is in the `<form id="myForm">` to a controller action that is expecting a `fulfillmentVM` object. Change your `Html.Hidden` fields to `Html.HiddenFor`. This will bind those values on post.

Use a `TextAreaFor` instead of a textarea for model binding, and make sure your viewmodel has an appropriate property for it.

```cs
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m._Requests[i].Request_ID)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m._Requests[i].Status, new { id = "myEdit", value = "" })
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.RejectMessage, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Remove the `<form id="myForm">` tags, they're unnecessary.

Keep the button as a submit button, and it will post to the Add_Fulfillment_Reject controller, passing all the bound values for your `fulfillmentVM`.

**Where to put the form**

Personally, I would put it starting right before the text box, move the hidden fields down there, too. End it right after the submit button.

```cs
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add_Fulfillment_Reject", "Feedback", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m._Requests[i].Request_ID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m._Requests[i].Status, new { id = "myEdit", value = "" })
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.RejectMessage, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
    // rest of modal code
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="finalSave" />
} // end form
```

Comment: so do i keep my modal inside the form and try your answer ? or place it outside?

Comment: I did that exactly but the submit button doesn't do anything . I placed a breakpoint to the reject method and I tried to click but it won't go there.

Comment: i missed the part of removing the `<form></form>` tags and this is what has been causing the error . i remove it and everything worked fine . thank you 